# Tell if the object is instantiated in a static method?

Tags: php, object

When calling a static method in PHP, can one tell if the method is running in an instantiated object or not?

Something like

```
public static function update( $value = NULL) {
  if ( self::is_instantiated() ) {
    update_db($this->value);
  } else {
    update_db($value);
  }
}
```

I don't want to simply test `! is_null($value)` because the method can be called publicly without passing a value.

I tried checking `isset()` for `$this` and `$this->property`, but that didn't work in the non-object context.

Comment: have you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: What do you mean? When inside the context of a static method you don't really have $this. 
You're disconnected from any object, you might try sending the reference of $this in any call and see if it exists.

Comment: Issn't it by default bad design to even run into this situation? Just asking.

Comment: @Yoshi it probably is, for reasons I am uneducated about, but now that I've thought it up, I seek to edify my ideas for a more complete understanding of how coding works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the `static` keyword. Static method is always static.

```
class A {
  public function whoami() {
    echo $this ? "i am object\n" : "i am class\n";
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->whoami();
A::whoami();
```

Result:

```
i am object
i am class
```

Comment: I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this in test.php on line 4` in PHP 5.6.13 with your verbatim code. I changed the line to `echo @isset($this) ? "i am object\n" : "i am class\n";`

Comment: So is the keyword `static` actually superfluous?

Comment: @user151841 Static methods are much more faster.